# Disable previous dates in kalcalendar view in iPhone

Tags: iphone, calendar, kal

I have implemented calendar view in iPhone using Kal library. The source code is here https://github.com/klazuka/Kal. I want disable the previous dates. Only the today date and the future date must be clickable.

Comment: Disable means, user interaction shouldn't want there?

Comment: @iAmbitious: Yes, i don't want user interaction.

Comment: From the official close reasons: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself_.

Answer (score 5):

Go to ***KalGridView.m*** & replace **-(void)setSelectedTile:(KalTileView *)tile** with code given below.

```
- (void)setSelectedTile:(KalTileView *)tile
{
    if (selectedTile != tile && [[KalDate dateFromNSDate:[NSDate date]] compare:tile.date] != NSOrderedDescending) 
    {
        selectedTile.selected = NO;
        selectedTile = [tile retain];
        tile.selected = YES;
        [delegate didSelectDate:tile.date];
    }
}
```

And now all those dates prior to current date will be disabled.

Comment: Yes this is one of the better way.